# Sharing MacOS X user folder on different machines

Tags: macos, mac

I wonder if the following idea can be realized:

A mac mini and a macbook - both have MacOS 10.7. (or higher) - and system on SSD.
Both also have their user folder moved to an external drive.

Is it possible (and how) to use the drive with the user folder on the MacBook when connected to external USB/thunderbold drive?

I would love that because it would save me from always copying lots of data for external work.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you are saying.
If you want to make an account accessible from multiple computers then you need to install OS X Server from the Mac App Store. Once this is done, setup the user. In your normal system preferences, click Users & Groups (this may be called something different based on your version of OS X, I have Mavericks), under "Login Items click "Join Server" and join the server that you just set up. Hope this helped!